# Is there a translation to English of this calculus book of Hermite?

Tags: reference-request

I would like to read "Cours de M. Hermite" (1891) ( https://archive.org/details/coursdemhermite00andogoog ) in English. It was translated to Russian as "Шарль Эрмит -- Курс анализа" (1936) but I did not find any translation to other idioms... Also, the French book is manuscript! I can understand a bit of French and Russian, but the reading is extremely tiresome for me in these languages --and the French in manuscript makes it harder. English is also not my native language, but I understand it much better than French or Russian... Unfortunately, it was not translated to Spanish.

Comment: Is the book special in some way? Alas, I don't know much about Hermite's legacy aside from the polynomials. Thank you for referencing the Russian translation, luckily it's my native language

Comment: @YuriyS I cannot speak for the OP, but it is my hunch that they ask this for the same reason I would have--V.I. Arnold extols its virtues in his essay 'On Teaching Mathematics' : "I remember well what a strong impression the calculus course by Hermite (which does exist in a
Russian translation!) made on me in my school years.
Riemann surfaces appeared in it, I think, in one of the first lectures [...]" and "The "obsolete" course by Hermite of one hundred years ago [...] was much more modern than those most boring calculus textbooks with which students are nowadays tormented."

Comment: @SamanthaY, oh, interesting, thank you